# Is it possible to take advantage of lowercase index on column using CQL filter on WFS?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, wfs, cql-filter, indexing

I am querying a WFS housed in geoserver - the data itself lives in a postgresql database. I would like to run case insensitive queries against the WFS and see there is an option to specify strToLowerCase on the field I am querying, but it doesn't appear to take advantage of the lowercase index I have created in postgresql. The table I am querying has several million records, and when using the strToLowerCase I run into memory issues. Is there a way I can do a case insensitive query on the data in the WFS and take advantage of the lowercase index that exists?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the GeoTools source code ([`FilterTOSqlHelper`](https://github.com/geotools/geotools/blob/master/modules/plugin/jdbc/jdbc-postgis/src/main/java/org/geotools/data/postgis/FilterToSqlHelper.java#L517)) it looks like your `strToLower` should be converted into a postgresql `lower` function and passed to the database.

So, I would turn the logging level upto GeoTools Debug and check that the SQL query really does have `lower` in it (if not raise a bug). Then paste that into pgadmin and do an explain on it to check if the index is being used.

You might also try the tip I give in this [blog post](https://blog.ianturton.com/postgis/2018/04/04/speeding-up-likes.html) to speed up case insensitive like queries.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I reviewed the log and strangely in the query the clause where strToLowerCase is applied doesn't show up. But I can see from the results that it worked. I just don't see any corresponding SQL for that part of the query.

Comment: I should add that though it returned the expected results, it was very slow.

Comment: was just reading this http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/filter/function_reference.html#filter-function-reference which says that most functions aren't understood by data stores and the expressions are evaluated in memory

Comment: Unless you are using a very recent version of GeoServer, the datastore does won't encode functions unless instructed to. Check your store configuration and see if the function encoding flag is enabled.

Comment: I didn't know that, but I am testing with master

Comment: @AndreaAime thanks for your comment, that was helpful and I enabled that in the data store. I am having issues beyond running case insensitive queries; I am querying a partitioned table (data partioned by state with a constraint set on the state). For example I have a query that takes 3 seconds to run in a sql editor, but when I query the wfs in the web application, it times out and gives a bad gateway error. Then I run the query again in the web app and get results in ~6 seconds. Why would this be?

Comment: You are going beyond the limits of what stackexchange support can offer. Please hop on the geoserver-users list instead, more people can help and we can have a discussion, here the format is just 1 question, 1 answer.